# How can I find the nearest possible open place for pygame collision detection?

Tags: python, collision-detection, pygame

I have the collision detection down. Now, I need to find where to move the player so that he is not clipping any blocks. Once I have the collision detection, I want to move the player to the nearest open space. Is there a way to do this easily? I know I need to find the overlapping rectangle, but I don't know how to do that. If you have any information on this post it please!

Comment: I haven't used pygame in particular, but one way to get out of a wall is to move in a direction until there is no collision. (This is also useful for non-bounding-rectangle collisions.)

Comment: That would work, but, which direction should I move?

Comment: @user982270 any direction. Start with, say, top left, and rotate clockwise. It's really up to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very common way is to try to move the player to a position, and then see if he's actually colliding with anything. If he isn't, move there, else, try another location. In pseudocode:

```
temp_pos = player.pos + (-1, -1) #move downleft one block
if player.pos != enemy.pos: #if the position is not occupied
    player.pos = temp_pos # move the player there.
else:
    #move player to another location and try again
```

Basically though, I'd have a list to off all the spaces (or available directions) around the player, and loop over that, instead of hard coding all the direction by hand.

Comment: I get that, but, some blocks have three open sides, so I want to find the closest side based on the player's position.

Comment: I don't understand then, because they'd all be next to the player right? Unless you're talking about 3D space, I guess. Show us the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

What I wanted was the collision rect for it. P3 in this code. Then, I can figure out the closest side to the collision and move the player accordingly.

```
def collide(self,p1, p2):
    p3=pygame.Rect()
    if p1.colliderect(p2):
        negpos=[0,0]
        dx=p1.x-p2.x
        dy=p1.y-p2.y
        if dx==abs(dx): negpos[0]=-1
        else: negpos[0]=1
        if dy==abs(dy): negpos[1]=-1
        else: negpos[1]=1
        if negpos==[-1,-1]:
            #topleft, bottomright
            p3tlx=p2.x
            p3tly=p2.y
            p3brx=p1.x+p1.w
            p3bry=p1.y+p1.h
        elif negpos==[-1,1]:
            # topright, bottomleft
            p3blx=p2.x
            p3bly=p2.x+p2.h
            p3trx=p1.x+p1.w
            p3try=p1.y
        elif negpos==[1,1]:
            # topleft, bottomright
            p3tlx=p1.x
            p3tly=pl.y
            p3brx=p2.x+p2.w
            p3bry=p2.y+p2.h
        elif negpos==[1,-1]:
            #topright, bottomleft
            p3trx=p2.x+p2.w
            p3try=p2.y
            p3blx=p1.x
            p3bly=p1.y-p1.h
        if p3trx:
            p3 = pygame.Rect(p3blx,p3try,abs(p3trx-p3blx),abs(p3try-p3bly))
        else:
            p3 = pygame.Rect(p3tlx,p3tly,abs(p3tlx-p3brx),abs(p3tly-p3bry))
```